# Chord of contact in polar coordinate

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Can you please help me to derive the equation of chord of contact for a circle in polar coordinate? I have found the equation in cartesian coordinate but I cannot map that into the polar coordinate. Any help would be appreciated.

Let suppose we want to derive the chord of contact that connects two points, e.g., $A(-\pi/3,1)$ and $B(\pi/4,1)$ on the unit circle. Center of the circle is $(0,0)$.

All the best,
Russell

Comment: If you have the equation in Cartesian coordinates, can't you put $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ to get the equation in polar coordinates?

Comment: It’s not very hard to determine the distance of the line from the origin and its direction directly in polar coordinates. From there, it’s a simple matter of plugging the numbers into one of the two standard polar equations of lines.